# jQuery open div on hover; automatic scroll through

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have an `UL` list with several links in it, and each item is linked to its own `DIV`. When the user hovers over UL link, proper `DIV` box is shown.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="productlist">
  <li><a href="#" id="link0" class="product-link">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="link2" class="product-link">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="link3" class="product-link">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="panel-overview boxlink" id="boxlink0"> Something goes here 1 </div>
<div class="panel-overview boxlink" id="boxlink1"> Something goes here 2 </div>
<div class="panel-overview boxlink" id="boxlink2"> Something goes here 3 </div>
```

and the JavaScript that makes it work (not a JavaScript expert, sorry):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var $boxes = $('.boxlink');
    $('.productlist .product-link').mouseover(function() {
        $boxes.hide().filter('#box' + this.id).show();
    });    
});
</script>
```

I was wondering how can I make the boxes to be scrolled through automatically every 3 to 4 seconds. So for example, first `DIV` is opened for 3 seconds, then the second, then the third...

[Here is the the live site](http://www.carelle-creations.mybigcommerce.com/collections/), since I haven't really described it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your description wasn't very clear to me, but this is how I interpereted it after viewing your website:
Cycle through the links to show the nice images. This will happen automatically.
BUT. If user wants to navigate, the cycle should stop

Here is the code for that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $boxes = $('.boxlink');
  var $links = $('.product-link');
  var cycle = false;
  var cycle_step = 0;

  $('.productlist .product-link').mouseenter(function() {
    boxActivate(this.id);
    stopCycle();
  });

  $('.productlist .product-link').mouseleave(function() {
    cycle = setTimeout(function(){
        startCycle();
    }, 1000);
  });

  var boxActivate = function(id){
    $boxes.hide().filter('#box' + id).show();
  }
  // cycle - only when mouse is not over links
  var startCycle = function(){
    cycle = setInterval(function(){
        boxActivate($links.get(cycle_step).id);
        cycle_step++;
        if(cycle_step==$links.length) {
            cycle_step=0;
        }
    }, 1000);
  }
  var stopCycle = function(){
    clearInterval(cycle);
  }

  startCycle();

});
```

Comment: This works perfectly!
If i can bore you for 2 more things (i know, not cool :\).
How to add some kind of fade effect to animation, and most importantly, how to leave the hover effect on LI items when the cycle is automatically going thru them all?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/terjeto/eeaAS/3/ (play around with fadeIn (and fadeOut can replace hide)

Answer (score 3):

try it like this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="productlist">
  <li><a href="#" id="0" class="product-link">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="1" class="product-link">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="2" class="product-link">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="panel-overview boxlink" id="boxlink0"> Something goes here 1 </div>
<div class="panel-overview boxlink" id="boxlink1"> Something goes here 2 </div>
<div class="panel-overview boxlink" id="boxlink2"> Something goes here 3 </div>
```

I changed the IDs of the `<a>`s.

JS

```
var current_box = 0; // Saves current shown box for timer
var timer_break = false; // Determines if timer shows boxes or not

// Function hides all boxes
function hide_boxes() {
    $('.boxlink').hide();
}

// Function shows box wit box_id and hides all other boxes
function show_box(box_id) { 
    hide_boxes();
    $('#boxlink'+box_id).show();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Bind show_box to HOVER Event
    $('.product-link').mouseover(function () {
        timer_break = true;
        show_box($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    // Bind hide_box to MOUSEOUT Event
    $('.product-link').mouseout(function () {
        timer_break = false;
        hide_boxes();
        show_box(current_id); // So there is no "gap" until the timer hits again
    });
    // Initiate Timer 
    var show_timer = setInterval(function () {
        if(!timer_break) {
            if(current_box < 2) {
                current_box++;
            } else {
                current_box = 0;
            }
            show_box(current_box);
        } 
    },3000);
    // Show first Box after loading
    show_box(current_box);
});
```

Working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8527K/

Comment: For some reason it isnt working properly, it flickers and isnt changing UL items.Do you have any other advice?
http://www.carelle-creations.mybigcommerce.com/collections/

Comment: P.S It is working when it is scrolling automatically thru the list, but when hover on menu item, page gets distorted

Comment: There are a few things wrong with the page to begin with.  For example, you are loading 2 different versions of jquery (lines 68 & 294).  Try to keep as much javascript in the `<head>` as possible. *EDIT* The fiddle @codezombie posted seems to work for me.

Comment: @tokmak See my answer below, it explains why your page gets distorted.

Comment: You made the href id's as single digit numbers. Why? It would be better to reference by index instead of using malformed ID's (should never start with a number).

Comment: @chrismauck - that was just for presentation purpose, of course one could use indexes as well. However, the question was more about the timer than about using indexes or ids.

Answer (score 0):

my solution
 [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u22G9/1/)

```
<ul class="product-list">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="product-info">
  <li>info 1</li>
  <li>info 2</li>
  <li>info 3</li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
var jq_info = $('.product-info li').hide();
var tm = null, 
    tm_index=0, 
    info_len = jq_info.length;

function show(index){
   clearTimeout(tm);

   if (index != undefined) tm_index = index;

   if (tm_index >= info_len) tm_index = 0;

   jq_info.hide().eq(tm_index).show();
   if (++tm_index >= info_len) tm_index=0;


   tm = setTimeout(show, 3000);   
}

$('.product-list a').mouseover(function(){
    show($(this).closest('li').index());
})

show(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another solution with some `data-target` attributes for pointing content to show/hide.

```
var $links = $('.product-link'), current_id = 0, timeout;
$links.mouseover(function(el) {
    var $this = $(this);       
    $this.addClass("hover")
    showLink($this);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});  

$links.mouseleave(function(el) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass("hover");
    timeout = setTimeout(cycle, 1000);
});

function showLink($link){
    var currentLink = $($links[current_id]);
    $(currentLink.data("target")).hide();
    $($link.data("target")).show();
    current_id = $link.parent().index();
} 

function cycle(){
    if($links.filter(".hover").length == 0){
        var next_id = (current_id + 1) % $links.length;
        showLink($($links[next_id]));
        timeout = setTimeout(cycle, 1000); 
    }           
}
timeout = setTimeout(cycle, 1000);
```

And as usual - a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtrYm/2/), note changes in html.

UPDATE: Your page has an error:

```
<a href="http://www.carelle-creations.mybigcommerce.com/steps/" id="link13" class="current_link">Steps</a>
```

doesnt have `product-link` class. Add that and my solution (and probably other's) will work normal.

UPDATE2:

You can replace

```
$(currentLink.data("target")).hide();
$($link.data("target")).show();
```

With

```
$("#box" + currentLink.attr("id")).hide();
$("#box" + $link.attr("id")).show();
```

And it will work without changing html. I've tested this on your actual page.