# jQuery UI issue, droppable and overflow scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I used the search and have not found an answer to my problem even if I've seen the same problem on other issues. I need that ".draggable" scroll  '#div1' when you introduce the element. I put the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/carlosnufe/7Rxst/

jQuery:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    appendto : "#div1",
    helper  : "clone"
})
$('#div1').droppable({
    scroll: true,
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div class="demo"></div>
    <div class="demo"></div>
    <div class="demo"></div>
    <div class="demo"></div>
    <div class="demo"></div>
    <div class="demo"></div>
    <div class="demo"></div>
    <div class="demo"></div>
    <div class="demo"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    <div class="draggable"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle is empty.

Comment: @carlosnufe always post your code here too instead of cheating the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code:

```
appendto : "#div1", // I assume this is a typo of "appendTo"
// ...
scroll: true, // AFAIK there is no option called "scroll" on a droppable
```

Now, from what I understand what you're trying to do is to make the `.droppable()` scroll to some predefined position when it accepts a `.draggable()`. The "accept a draggable" event in a droppable is actually called `drop`:

```
$("#div1").droppable({
    drop: function() {
        // myPosition can be this.height if you want to scroll all the way down
        $(this).scrollTop(myPosition);
    }
});
```

(there is also an `accept` option, but using it in such a way would be abusing its purpose)

I've put this in your [fiddle here as a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hfgHn/). I've also made a few other tweaks, so you can actually see it working (note that you can't have regular `div`s on top of `position:relative;float:left;` elements, thus I'm also adding the `.demo` class to them)

---

In the case where you want the `.demo`-s to accept the drops, you don't want to make the whole container `#div1` a droppable element. What you can do, is manipulate its `.scrollTop` value whenever you fulfill certain conditions while dragging your draggable element.

You can do this with either the `drag` event on the draggable or `over` event on the droppable. It's a matter of preference, as both are rather expensive, but I'd prefer going with the second one:

```
$('.demo').droppable({
    over: function(e, ui) {
        if(conditionForScrollingUp) {
            // scroll container up
            $("#div1").scrollTop($("#div1").scrollTop() - magicNumber);
        } else if(conditionForScrollingDown) {
            // scroll container down
            $("#div1").scrollTop($("#div1").scrollTop() + magicNumber);
        }
    }
});
```

This will unfortunately slow down your page quite a bit, especially if you have a large number of `div.demo`-s.

[Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfgHn/1/) showing this working with your example. To get it to scroll, drag the draggable objects over the top or bottom of the `#div1` container.

A further extension you might want to do is to get it to scroll smoothly while your mouse pointer is standing still. You can do this with some creative use of `setTimeout` or `setInterval`; I won't go into detail on this, as you can find good explanations in either of these questions: [jQuery open div on hover; automatic scroll through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873097/) and [Scroll on hover, click for speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188952/)

Comment: Hi bigt,
Your pov (point..) is very interesting but isn't exactly that i want. Really i need to put the .dragabble elements into .demo elements. My problem is that when i drag into .demo elements (in my real code) i can't put in the hidden elements and i was asking for a kind of auto scroll. Sorry my english ;)

Comment: amazing... really amazing. Thanks you so much