# JQuery UI dragging into sortable not scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the `jquery ui draggable` and `sortable` together, as i can drop new items into the sortable from a draggable, and sort the items in the sortable.
The div that contains the sortable has a fix height, and it is set to be scrolled if it has too many items. My problem is, when i'm dragging a new item into the sortable, the scrolling is not available like when i'm moving items inside the sortable. The mouse wheel scroll is disable when dragging as well.

My [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkeresztes/qAS93/10/)

Is there a way to enable scrolling in the div when I'm dragging something new into it, by moving the new item to the bottom of the div, or with the mouse wheel?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Setting the droppable list to be overflow: auto and position: relative, Will make your list scrollable with your mouse wheel

Comment: Tried it but the list is still not scrollable while dragging an item over it.

Comment: It needed to be put in a wrapper around the div element. Made a fiddle for you. http://jsfiddle.net/qAS93/11/

Comment: It's still not what I'd like, sorry maybe I did not word my question right. I don't want the draggable ul to be scrollable, but I want the sortable ul (or the div with the fix height) to be scrollable while I'm dragging an item from the draggable over the sortable.

Comment: Ok, that is what my code does. Except it does both lists scrollable.
Check out this answer, his fiddle worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24516370/3165725

Comment: Setting the appendTo for the draggable seems to be the trick. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Setting the appendTo for the draggable seems to be the trick.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513202/jquery-ui-issue-droppable-and-overflow-scroll/24516370#24516370

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> `scroll: true`

**Find Method**

Doc http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#scroll

> Automatically scroll the document when the draggable is moved beyond
>   the viewport. Set the scroll option to true to enable auto-scrolling,
>   and fine-tune when scrolling is triggered and its speed with the
>   scrollSensitivity and scrollSpeed options.

Comment: The document becomes scrollable with and without the scroll: true, but the div does not either way.