# Make three div autoplay and show their hidden text

Tags: jquery, html, css, autoplay

I got three div with a `display: none` text below them. When user hover to one of the div, it will show the hidden text.

Now, I wan't to add additional function where if no user hover to those div, the div will just auto show their hidden text sort of like autoplay carousel.

What approach I can take to make it? jquery? Or can I make it using CSS only?

PS: I have no idea what I can search for to find this kind of function.

```css
.col-md-2 {
    float: left;
}

.product-icon-box {
    width: 128px;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-certified, .product-icon-box-desc-warranty, .product-icon-box-desc-buyback, .product-icon-box-desc-shipping {
    display: none;
    width: 512px;
}

.product-icon-box:hover {
    background: #E6DCD0;
}

.product-icon-box:hover .product-icon-box-desc-certified {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

.product-icon-box:hover .product-icon-box-desc-warranty {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -128px;
    background: #fff;
}

.product-icon-box:hover .product-icon-box-desc-buyback {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -256px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="row mb30">
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center product-icon-box">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-ori.png" /> 
       <i>Authenticity & Restoration</i>
     </a>
     <div class="product-icon-box-desc-certified">
     <p class="certified-title">CERTIFIED AUTHENTIC</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Aliquam libero lorem, rutrum vitae dolor quis, pellentesque placerat lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Sed ullamcorper dictum libero eget aliquet. In mauris est, blandit ut aliquam at, tristique ac orci. Quisque mollis, lectus in tempor bibendum, libero dui aliquet odio, vitae dictum arcu elit sit amet eros. Maecenas pellentesque nunc enim, id porta orci pretium vitae. Nam pellentesque sem vitae neque iaculis, vel tincidunt ligula mollis. In fringilla dictum tortor eu accumsan. Donec ac neque et ligula egestas venenatis. Donec malesuada ultricies posuere. Nullam risus nunc, finibus sit amet nisi ac, molestie tempor dui.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center product-icon-box">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-waranty.png" /> 
       <i>12 Months Warranty</i>
     </a>
     <div class="product-icon-box-desc-warranty">
     <p class="certified-title">CERTIFIED PRE-OWNED WATCHES WARRANTY</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Donec ac nibh urna. Mauris porta quis lacus id efficitur. Mauris sit amet congue nunc. Nullam tellus lacus, vehicula non viverra id, fringilla eu sapien. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum nulla in ex facilisis blandit non eu risus. Nam imperdiet sed risus fermentum tristique. Integer elementum vitae diam non volutpat. Praesent in mi blandit nunc efficitur elementum. Etiam dapibus dui dui, vitae pretium urna dapibus at.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center product-icon-box">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-buyback.png" /> 
       <i>Buy Back / Trade In Guarantee</i>
     </a>
     <div class="product-icon-box-desc-buyback">
     <p class="certified-title">LIFE TIME BUY BACK / TRADE-IN TERMS AND CONDITION</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Phasellus dolor nisi, ullamcorper ac mauris posuere, scelerisque viverra urna. Vivamus eleifend ullamcorper ex condimentum iaculis. Nunc volutpat massa id dui imperdiet interdum. Nullam quis libero sed velit pretium ornare. In vestibulum sollicitudin est, a fermentum libero. Praesent in ultricies libero. Integer eget dignissim diam. Donec volutpat ultrices auctor. Proin euismod magna ut nulla condimentum tempor. Donec at elit magna. Etiam pretium, augue at fringilla porta, neque nibh pulvinar nibh, at posuere ex dui ac enim. Nunc erat nibh, rhoncus non varius et, blandit in purus.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're asking. So instead of hover you want them to just show the hidden text sequentially?

Comment: @CodeSpent I want to keep the hover function. And when no people hover to those div, yeah just show the hidden text sequentially. (Example: Show Authenticity &restoration hidden text -> Show 12 months warranty hidden text  and so on

Answer (score 0):

setInterval fadeIn and fadeOut are key function.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/

Comment: Finish look into it, but I think it's kind of different than my html setup. Mine one is when hover to one of the div, the div below it will show + there is brown background for the logo. While if I use the above example, it only gonna rotate displaying the logo.

Comment: I think the logic I need to make is, to set time interval for those div to be in hover state for certain amount of time and keep rotate

Comment: Answers should include code.  Links are fine but the answer must have value *when the link does not work*.  Put worthwhile example code in the answer or it's nothing more than a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found an answer, but not so much perfect yet, based on this topic [jQuery open div on hover; automatic scroll through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873097/jquery-open-div-on-hover-automatic-scroll-through)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $boxes = $('.boxlink');
  var $links = $('.product-link');
  var cycle = false;
  var cycle_step = 0;

  $('.productlist .product-link').mouseenter(function() {
    boxActivate(this.id);
    stopCycle();
  });

  $('.productlist .product-link').mouseleave(function() {
    cycle = setTimeout(function(){
        startCycle();
    }, 1000);
  });

  var boxActivate = function(id){
    $boxes.hide().filter('#box' + id).show();
  }
  // cycle - only when mouse is not over links
  var startCycle = function(){
    cycle = setInterval(function(){
        boxActivate($links.get(cycle_step).id);
        cycle_step++;
        if(cycle_step==$links.length) {
            cycle_step=0;
        }
    }, 3000);
  }
  var stopCycle = function(){
    clearInterval(cycle);
  }

  startCycle();

});
```

```css
.product-link {
    float: left;
    width: 128px;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-certified, .product-icon-box-desc-warranty, .product-icon-box-desc-buyback, .product-icon-box-desc-shipping {
    display: none;
    width: 512px;
}

.product-link:hover {
    background: #E6DCD0;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-certified {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-warranty {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -128px;
    background: #fff;
}

.product-icon-box-desc-buyback {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -256px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productlist">
    <div id="link0" class="product-link">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-ori.png" /> 
       <i>Authenticity & Restoration</i>
     </a>
     <div id="boxlink0" class="product-icon-box-desc-certified boxlink">
     <p class="certified-title">CERTIFIED AUTHENTIC</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Aliquam libero lorem, rutrum vitae dolor quis, pellentesque placerat lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Sed ullamcorper dictum libero eget aliquet. In mauris est, blandit ut aliquam at, tristique ac orci. Quisque mollis, lectus in tempor bibendum, libero dui aliquet odio, vitae dictum arcu elit sit amet eros. Maecenas pellentesque nunc enim, id porta orci pretium vitae. Nam pellentesque sem vitae neque iaculis, vel tincidunt ligula mollis. In fringilla dictum tortor eu accumsan. Donec ac neque et ligula egestas venenatis. Donec malesuada ultricies posuere. Nullam risus nunc, finibus sit amet nisi ac, molestie tempor dui.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="link1" class="product-link">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-waranty.png" /> 
       <i>12 Months Warranty</i>
     </a>
     <div id="boxlink1" class="product-icon-box-desc-warranty boxlink">
     <p class="certified-title">CERTIFIED PRE-OWNED WATCHES WARRANTY</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Donec ac nibh urna. Mauris porta quis lacus id efficitur. Mauris sit amet congue nunc. Nullam tellus lacus, vehicula non viverra id, fringilla eu sapien. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum nulla in ex facilisis blandit non eu risus. Nam imperdiet sed risus fermentum tristique. Integer elementum vitae diam non volutpat. Praesent in mi blandit nunc efficitur elementum. Etiam dapibus dui dui, vitae pretium urna dapibus at.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="link2" class="product-link">
     <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://iceiceicy.com/wingwah/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/icon-buyback.png" /> 
       <i>Buy Back / Trade In Guarantee</i>
     </a>
     <div id="boxlink2" class="product-icon-box-desc-buyback boxlink">
     <p class="certified-title">LIFE TIME BUY BACK / TRADE-IN TERMS AND CONDITION</p>
     <p class="certified-desc">Phasellus dolor nisi, ullamcorper ac mauris posuere, scelerisque viverra urna. Vivamus eleifend ullamcorper ex condimentum iaculis. Nunc volutpat massa id dui imperdiet interdum. Nullam quis libero sed velit pretium ornare. In vestibulum sollicitudin est, a fermentum libero. Praesent in ultricies libero. Integer eget dignissim diam. Donec volutpat ultrices auctor. Proin euismod magna ut nulla condimentum tempor. Donec at elit magna. Etiam pretium, augue at fringilla porta, neque nibh pulvinar nibh, at posuere ex dui ac enim. Nunc erat nibh, rhoncus non varius et, blandit in purus.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

The thing now is, how can I add the background color for the current .product-link div? (See what I mean when user manually hover)